# BIRT : org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Birt]]

Tags: apache, tomcat, birt

I want to setup BIRT : [http://www.eclipse.org/birt/]

I have followed the official documentation on how to integrate BIRT 4.6 with apache-tomcat 8.0.36.

I went through all the related answer on stack-overflow but that did not resolved my specific problem.
apache-tomcat generate log when i try to start BIRT from Apache-tomcat manager.

System Information:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

apache-tomcat log details:
27-Jul-2016 12:46:47.279 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
27-Jul-2016 12:46:47.284 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
27-Jul-2016 12:46:47.322 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
27-Jul-2016 12:47:20.759 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/Birt'
27-Jul-2016 12:47:20.894 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log FAIL - Application at context path /Birt could not be started
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Birt]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:284)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResource.getJarInputStreamWrapper(JarResource.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource.doGetInputStream(AbstractArchiveResource.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractResource.getInputStream(AbstractResource.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5111)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)

Comment: This may be due to some of your dependencies are signed jar files, You can solve the problem by removing the signature files from your manifest.

Comment: I solve this Problem with hs.chandra commit.                                         this is due signature.                                                                                                     $zip -d yourjar.jar 'META-INF/.SF' 'META-INF/.RSA' 'META-INF/*SF'